# Return Json from Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, json

How can I return Json format from Oracle using php? I did this and debugged with firebug, there were no error and it did not return anything...but it printed done!

```
<?php

$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$host = "myhost/myservicename";

$conn = oci_connect($user, $pass, $host);
$sql  = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE rownum <100");

oci_execute($sql);

$rows = array();
while($r = oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$rows[] = $r;
 }
$locations =(json_encode($rows));
echo 'done!';
?>
```

Comment: remove the echo 'done' and replace it with echo $locations

Comment: You could var_dump($locations) to see the content of your encoding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is what ever that you have the page print.

So change `'done!'` to `$locations`